# Как можно изменить кодировку файлов в VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, github

При пуше файлов на гитхаб из VS19 русские символы оторажаются некорректно. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Справа снизу кодировка -> Save with Encoding.

Comment: @Sherlock эта штука доступна только для HTML и СSS ,а мне надо для С++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файл -> Сохранить как

В открывшемся диалоге жмем стрелочку вниз и Сохранить с кодировкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И далее выбираем нужную кодировку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И проверьте, не включена ли следующая опция:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое .А как применить можно ко всем файлам и всегда .Можно как то поставить по умолчанию?

Comment: @Vanya Через [EditorConfig](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019) должно работать для текущего проекта. Но текущие файлы в UTF скорее всего придется пересохранить/переконвертировать в нужную кодировку.