# Прочтение текстовых файлов

Tags: c++

Суть вопроса:Как вывести на экран название туроператора, и цену путевки, если название курорта начинается на «Трус», а количество дней более 18. Вот что написано в текстовом файле 1) Название курорта 2)Цена 3)Название туроператора 4)колличество дней

```
Трустровка:10000 Феерия@24
Лазаревское:20000 Альянс@10
Гострусо:30000 Сиеста@19
Трустоба:5900 Корал@17
Алдер:6780 Веди@20
Трустервазия:25000 Туристическая@20
```

Мой код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <WINDOWS.h>
using namespace std;

struct pytivka
{
    char nazvaniekyrorta[100];
    int cenapytivki[100];
    char nazvanieoperatora[100];
    int colvodnei[100];
}object;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");
    ifstream phile("pytivka.txt");
    if (!phile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!";
        return 0;
    }
    pytivka data;
    char buffer[256];
    const char pattern[] = "Трус";
    while (phile.getline(buffer, 256))
    {
        char* token = strtok(buffer, ": @");
        strcpy(data.nazvaniekyrorta, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ": @");
        data.cenapytivki = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ": @");
        strcpy(data.nazvaniekyrorta, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ": @");
        data.colvodnei = atoi(token);

        if (strncmp(data.nazvaniekyrorta, pattern, sizeof(pattern) - 1) == 0 && data.colvodnei > 18 )
        {
            cout << data.nazvanieoperatora << data.cenapytivki;
        }
    }
    phile.close();
}
```

Comment: Вместо 4-х `const char first; ...` используйте `const char pattern[] = "Трус";` и тогда для сравнения  пишите `if (strncmp(data.nazvaniekyrorta, pattern, sizeof(pattern) - 1) == 0) { // OK ... }` (это намного проще, чем вы пытаетесь сделать) / Также во всех strtok() лучше использовать одну и ту же строку разделителей -- `": @"` -- это точно будет работать. / Ну, и массивы int в описании структуры `pytivka` не нужны, переменной `data.object.cenapytivki` у вас нет, наверное надо просто `data.cenapytivki` и т.п. мелкие ошибки поправьте

Comment: Можете посмотреть что тут надо изменить и добавить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да воспользуйтесь вы, наконец, возможностями C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <clocale>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

bool is_space(std::ifstream::int_type symbol, const std::locale& loc)
{
    return ( symbol != std::ifstream::traits_type::eof() && 
        std::isspace(std::ifstream::traits_type::to_char_type(symbol), loc) );
}

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    std::ifstream file("pytivka.txt");
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    const auto loc = file.getloc();
    while (true)
    {
        //Считываем пробелы перед названием курорта
        while (is_space(file.peek(), loc))
            file.get();

        std::string spa;
        std::getline(file, spa, ':');

        int price;
        file >> price;

        //Считываем пробелы перед названием туроператора
        while (is_space(file.peek(), loc))
            file.get();

        std::string tour;
        std::getline(file, tour, '@');

        int days;
        file >> days;

        if (file.fail())
            break;

        if (spa.find("Трус") == 0 && days > 18)
            cout << tour << " " << price << endl;

    }
    file.close();
}
```

Приведённый код у меня вывел:

```
Феерия 10000
Туристическая 25000
```

Comment: Вывелась ошибка в https://yapx.ru/v/KjvUI

Comment: Добавьте заголовочный файл `#include <locale>`. Моя ошибка — пропустил при копировании.

Comment: Все компилируется , но ничего не выводит

Comment: с чем это может быть связано , что ничего не выводит компилятор?

Comment: @Young, вероятно проблемы с кодировкой. Файл с исходными данными и строковые литералы в файле исходного кода записаны в разных кодировках. Отсюда получаем несовпадение при поиске `spa.find("Трус")`. Храните данные и файл исходного кода в одинаковой кодировке. См.: [Как можно изменить кодировку файлов в VisualStudio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1151291).

Comment: @Young Можете выполнить программу как [здесь](https://ideone.com/EXpmGW). И написать, что она вам выведет?

Comment: Все я нашел ошибку, просто strcpy(data.nazvaniekyrorta, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ": @");
        data.cenapytivki = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ": @");
        strcpy(data.nazvaniekyrorta, token); два раза написал название курорта